# HTML tags in XML file, how to ignore HTML tags while XML parsing

Tags: html, xml, parsing, tags

Thanks in advance,

I am using NSXMLParser to parse xml file, in my application,

my xml file is like this

< item >
  < ID >
     123456
  < /ID >
  < category >
     Films
  < /category >
  < Heading >
     HollyWood films
  < /Heading >
  < Author >
     samule
  < /Author >
  < imageFull >
     http://tree_one.jpg
  < /imageFull >
  < contentFull >
     New York, the stars will fly to Las Vegas for another one. On New Year’s eve          no shoot because it’s been left free for partying. 
     < strong >
        Costly choices 
     < /strong >
     < b > A source < /b > 
           adds that Sajid wants to make up for the missed family 
     < br >time by allowing them to have
         a blast without bothering about anything.
  < /contentFull >
  < PubDate >
    Monday, 14 December 2009
  < /PubDate >
< /item >

my question is when i get the content in < contentFull > tag, it is not coping the content to the string.
i think because of the internal HTML tags its not getting the content.

how can i solve this, to ignore HTML tags to perform as mentioned in the xml file(bold, break, strong,... etc).

plz guide me, is it possible in NSXMLParser?,

Answer (score 2):

Use `<![CDATA[<html> ... </html> ]]`

Comment: can u plz explain how can i use this.

Comment: You can read about using XML CDATA here. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: The link is broken. Can you please edit your answer to explain what it does and how to use it?